# What is the best way to loop through integers with at most k bits ON?

Tags: algorithm

I need to loop through all n-bit integers which has at most k bits ON (bits 1), where 0 < n <= 32 and 0 <= k <= n. For example, if n = 4 and k = 2 then these numbers are (in binary digits): 0000, 0001, 0010, 0100, 1000, 0011, 0101, 0110, 1001, 1010, 1100. The order in which these numbers are looped through is not important, but each is visited only once.

Currently I am using this straightforward algorithm:

```
for x = 0 to (2^n - 1)
    count number of bits 1 in x
    if count <= k
        do something with x
    end if
end for
```

I think this algorithm is inefficient because it has to loop through too many numbers. For example, if n = 32 and k = 2 then it has to loop through 2^32 numbers to find only 529 numbers (which have <= 2 bits 1).

My question is: is there any more efficient algorithm to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bit hack to generate all integers with a given number of 1s](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281951/bit-hack-to-generate-all-integers-with-a-given-number-of-1s)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight It's not a duplicate, but similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are going to need to make your own bitwise counting algorithm for incrementing the loop counter.  Basically, for calculating the next number in the sequence, if there are fewer than k '1' bits, increment normally, if there are k '1' bits, pretend the '0' bits after the least significant '1' don't exist and increment normally.

Another way of saying it is that with a standard counter you add 1 to the least significant bit and carry.  In your case, when there are k number of '1's you will add in the 1 to the lowest '1' bit.

For instance if k is 2 and you have `1010` ignore the last `0` and increment the `101` so you get `110` and then add in the `0` for `1100`.

Here is Pseudocode for incrementing the number:

```
Count 1 bits in current number
If number of 1's is < k
  number = number + 1
Else
  shift_number = number of 0 bits after least significant 1 bit
  number = number >> shift_number
  number = number + 1
  number = number << shift_number
```

Comment: Excellent! And this algorithm is very fast.

Comment: +1 for a very neat algorithm!  It may be faster (on processors without instructions to count trailing zeros) to replace the else statements with the equivalent code of "number = ((number|(number-1))+1)"

Answer (score 1):

Take the answer to [Bit hack to generate all integers with a given number of 1s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281951/bit-hack-to-generate-all-integers-with-a-given-number-of-1s) and loop over `[1,k]`. That will generate each integer with up to `k` bits once.

Comment: Yeah, but that algorithm is a bit more complicated then needed since it has to avoid numbers with fewer than k bits as well.  When you allow those numbers, you can make a much simpler algorithm that only loops once, and you have the added potential benefit of going in order (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you have to set 2 bits in 4, the lowest bit set must be at most the third (counting from 0...3) and the highest at least the second.

So you could loop with 2 loops

```
for lowest in 0 to (n-k)
  for highest in lowest + 1 to 3 
    (0000).setBit (lowest).setBit (highest)
```

Since you don't want to write 16 loops for 16 bits, you might transform this idea into a recursive one.

Answer (score 0):

Combinatorics.

If you have integers with `n` bit length and `r` bits set then there are `nCr` such numbers. Simply use a combination generator and iterate over the combinations as appropriate.

Comment: This is the most sensible solution.

Comment: @Muhd: You *do* realize that a number that has bits 2 and 3 set has *exactly* the same value as one that has bits 3 and 2 set, right?

Comment: You are right... I have a rule of a thumb for remembering that "with permuations, order matters" and that led me astray since the order of 0's and 1's matters, but not the order of just the 1's.

Answer (score -1):

you can use a while loop as shown below. This loop will only loop for no of bits on. incase your no of bits is fixed you can use a break

```
countbits = 0
while num > 0
    num = num & (num-1)
    countbits = countbits + 1
end while
```

eg:
if 64(1000000) it will loop only once, 
if 72(1001000) then 2 times