# How to get all one and two letter combinations in order from a word?

Tags: java, algorithm

For example, there is a line

```
String str = "program";
```

It is necessary to get all possible combinations, such as:

- p-r-o-g-r-a-m
- p-r-o-g-r-am
- p-r-o-g-ra-m
- pr-og-r-am

and so on.

How do I do this in java? Or at least tell me a general algorithm (with an example)?

It is not a problem to break the deadline, at least one character at a time, at least two, for example

```
for (int i = 0; i <str.length () - 1; i = i +2) {
             String strTemp = str.charAt (i) + "" + str.charAt (i + 1);
               System.out.println (strTemp);
}
```

But how to get (bypass) all possible combinations of one and two is not clear how to program.

Comment: Throwing some thoughts in: each letter has a state of either "paired" or "not paired". Taking that further, we have a boolean 1/0 for "pairedness" of each letter. Next imagine a counter which ticks up from all 0's (a 0 per letter) through to all 1's (a 1 per letter).

Comment: Instead of considering the letters being paired as @LukeBriggs suggested, I would work with the gaps between letters. They can be paired or not. Two neighboring gaps may not be paired simultaneously. A recursive method is maybe the easiest approach to enumerate all possibilites.

Comment: Yeah, "dash" vs. "no dash" is a simpler concept. Re-reading the question the restriction of them being in two's doesn't actually appear to be necessary; i.e. it seems like `progr-am` is valid too, thus it can just be a straight counter representing dash states.

Comment: No, "progr-am" not valid. exactly 1 or 2 letters per part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this using recursive programming:

```
public Set<String> combination(String str){
    final Set<String> results = new HashSet<>();
    if(str.length() == 0)
        return results;
    if(str.length() == 1){
        results.add(str);
        return results;
    }
    if(str.length() == 2){
        results.add(str.charAt(0) + "-" + str.charAt(1));
        results.add(str);
        return results;
    }
    String head = str.substring(0, 1);
    final Set<String> remaining = combination(str.substring(1));
    remaining.forEach(s -> {
        int i = s.indexOf("-");
        if(i == 1){
            results.add(head + s);
            results.add(head + "-" + s);
        } else if(s.length() == 2){
            results.add(head + "-" + s);
        } else if(i == 2){
            results.add(head + "-" + s);
        }
    });
    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**My suggestion:**

Encode a single letter as a `0` and a pair as a `1`. Now all decompositions map to binary numbers. Enumerate all naturals, starting from `0`, up to `2^(L-2)` for a word of length `L`, skipping the numbers such that `2O+Z>L` (`O` ones and `Z` zeroes).

E.g.

```
p-r-o-g-r-a-m: 0000000
p-r-o-g-r-am:   000001
p-r-o-g-ra-m:   000010
p-r-o-gr-am:     00011
     ....
pr-o-g-r-a-m:   100000
```

I am not sure that this is efficient but for now I see no better way to enumerate than trying all naturals and skipping the incompatible ones.

---

**Update:**

Check this: [What is the best way to loop through integers with at most k bits ON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458267/what-is-the-best-way-to-loop-through-integers-with-at-most-k-bits-on)

Answer (score 0):

I like the recursive approach from hatef Alipoor. But i would put it in smaller methods to make it more readable.

Here is my code:

```
public class WordCombiner {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new WordCombiner("program").run();
  }
  
  private final String word;
  
  public WordCombiner(String word) {
    this.word = word;
  }
  
  public void run() {
    resolveCobination("", 0);
  }
  
  private void resolveCobination(String builder, int currentIndex) {
    appendSingleCharacter(builder, currentIndex);
    if (currentIndex+1 < word.length()) {
      appendDoubleCharacter(builder, currentIndex);
    }
  }

  private void appendSingleCharacter(String builder, int currentIndex) {
    builder = builder + word.charAt(currentIndex++);
    resolveOrPrint(builder, currentIndex);
  }

  private void appendDoubleCharacter(String builder, int currentIndex) {
    builder = builder + word.charAt(currentIndex++);
    builder = builder + word.charAt(currentIndex++);
    resolveOrPrint(builder, currentIndex);
  }

  private void resolveOrPrint(String builder, int currentIndex) {
    if (currentIndex < word.length()) {
      builder = builder + "-";
      resolveCobination(builder, currentIndex);
    } else {
      System.out.println(builder);
    }
  }
  
}
```