# Query points on the vertices of a Hamming cube

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, computational-geometry, hamming-distance

I have N points that lie only on the vertices of a cube, of dimension D, where D is something like 3.

A vertex may not contain any point. So every point has coordinates in {0, 1}<sup>D</sup>. I am only interested in *query time*, as long as the memory cost is reasonable ( not exponential in N for example :) ).

Given a query that lies on one of the cube's vertices and an input parameter `r`, find all the vertices (thus points) that have *hamming distance* <= `r` with the query.

What's the way to go in a [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) environment?

---

I am thinking of a kd-tree, but I am not sure and want help, any input, even approximative, would be appreciated! Since *hamming distance* comes into play, bitwise manipulations should help (e.g. XOR).

Comment: A downvote, why? :/ Please Mr. Downvoter, suggest how I can improve my question -  you didn't even cast a downvote to help me...!

Comment: Not my -1, but as I understand "the curse of dimensionality", it means exactly that for D >> 1, no one knows a good way to solve this problem.  As D increases, the dumbest-possible algorithm (check each of your N points to see if it's within r of the query point) quickly becomes the best-known algorithm.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, as one of the guys that created [kd-geraf](https://github.com/gsamaras/kd_GeRaF), I can say that we don't have to do with the curse of dimensionality that much here, I mean D will never be 10.000 in my case, but thanks for the tip, I will fix it! ;)

Comment: Using some bitmath tricks you can simply enumerate all vertices that are at distance exactly `k`, then just loop `k` up to `r`. I've answered this before, let me just go find it..

Comment: Yes @harold, you commented at the same time I commented that bitwise manipulations should help, I am looking for something like it. Great, I will wait!

Comment: I [found it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40253731/555045), but the context was a quite different and it was Java.. still, the same idea applies

Comment: @harold interesting, I would suggest that you modify it a bit to match my question and post an answer, please. :)

Comment: "N points that lie only on the vertices of a cube" and "A vertex may not contain any point": hem, isn't that contradictory ? What I am missing ?

Comment: "D is something like 3": why worry then ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I am sorry to see you downvoting. In my real applications I am mapping points to a hypercube (points are being assigned to a hypercube), but during that mapping process some vertices might not get any point! Well D = 3 is a super strong assumption, I just had to make to survive the -2 at that time. The idea is to get an answer for that and then generalize it myself!

Comment: "to survive the -2": ??? And you didn't answer my question.

Comment: Yes @YvesDaoust, I was about to delete the question since it was too broad (see comments above), so I decided to make some strong assumptions. I thought I did, what didn't I cover? :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a nice bithack to go from one bitmask with `k` bits set to the [lexicographically next permutation](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#NextBitPermutation), which means it's fairly simple to loop through all masks with `k` bits set. XORing these masks with an initial value gives all the values at hamming distance exactly `k` away from it.

So for `D` dimensions, where `D` is less than 32 (otherwise change the types),

```
uint32_t limit = (1u << D) - 1;
for (int k = 1; k <= r; k++) {
    uint32_t diff = (1u << k) - 1;
    while (diff <= limit) {
        // v is the input vertex
        uint32_t vertex = v ^ diff;
        // use it
        diff = nextBitPermutation(diff);
    }
}
```

Where `nextBitPermutation` may be implemented in C++ as something like (if you have `__builtin_ctz`)

```
uint32_t nextBitPermutation(uint32_t v) {
    // see https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#NextBitPermutation
    uint32_t t = v | (v - 1);
    return (t + 1) | (((~t & -~t) - 1) >> (__builtin_ctz(v) + 1));
}
```

Or for MSVC (not tested)

```
uint32_t nextBitPermutation(uint32_t v) {
    // see https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#NextBitPermutation
    uint32_t t = v | (v - 1);
    unsigned long tzc;
    _BitScanForward(&tzc, v); // v != 0 so the return value doesn't matter
    return (t + 1) | (((~t & -~t) - 1) >> (tzc + 1));
}
```

---

If D is *really* low, 4 or lower, the old `popcnt`-with-`pshufb` works really well and generally everything just lines up well, like this:

```
uint16_t query(int vertex, int r, int8_t* validmask)
{
    // validmask should be array of 16 int8_t's,
    // 0 for a vertex that doesn't exist, -1 if it does
    __m128i valid = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)validmask);
    __m128i t0 = _mm_set1_epi8(vertex);
    __m128i r0 = _mm_set1_epi8(r + 1);
    __m128i all =        _mm_setr_epi8(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15);
    __m128i popcnt_lut = _mm_setr_epi8(0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2,  2,  3,  2,  3,  3,  4);
    __m128i dist = _mm_shuffle_epi8(popcnt_lut, _mm_xor_si128(t0, all));
    __m128i close_enough = _mm_cmpgt_epi8(r0, dist);
    __m128i result = _mm_and_si128(close_enough, valid);
    return _mm_movemask_epi8(result);
}
```

This should be fairly fast; fast compared to the bithack above (`nextBitPermutation`, which is fairly heavy, is used a lot there) and also compared to looping over all vertices and testing whether they are in range (even with builtin `popcnt`, that automatically takes at least 16 cycles and the above shouldn't, assuming everything is cached or even permanently in a register). The downside is the result is annoying to work with, since it's a mask of which vertices both exist and are in range of the queried point, not a list of them. It would combine well with doing some processing on data associated with the points though.

This also scales down to D=3 of course, just make none of the points >= 8 valid. D>4 can be done similarly but it takes more code then, and since this is really a brute force solution that is only fast due to parallelism it fundamentally gets slower exponentially in D.

Comment: I can use `unit8_t`, since D won't be more than this, right? But the problem here is that I don't understand which is the *query*, is it `v`? And where are my points? Some (many?) vertices of the cube might be empty, so not all permutations are pointing to points.

Comment: @gsamaras yes, `v`. And yes, this stops being a good idea if N is much less than 2^D, in which case this spends too much time hitting empty space. Are you in a situation like that?

Comment: Actually for D < 9 I have an other idea, just have to work that out a bit

Comment: No, D should be something like log(N)/2. So what you are doing, in every iteration, is that based on the query `v`, you produce ALL the possible permutations with hamming distance `k`? For example v = 111, k = 1 and D = 3, then you produce 011, 101, 110? Maybe I should make a minimal example to check this. | About the new idea: Oh cool, maybe you can post it as a second answer. :)

Comment: @gsamaras the new idea isn't working well yet, the details would depend a lot on what you would actually do with the results.

Comment: I have N points and one query, right? I want to find all the points that satisfy this: `hamming_dist(query, current_point) <= r`. I want to report these points, that's it, that's my goal, is that clear?

Comment: Ok that's just a bit more annoying than, say, counting them or summing corresponding values or something like that. Anyway, is D=4 of interest? It works out particularly well.

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer. To be honest I am yet sure on how to report the points that satisfy `hamming_dist(query, current_point) <= r`, yet so I am trying to understand on how to use your `query()`, can you please give an intuitive example (not a minimal one)? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128863/discussion-between-harold-and-gsamaras).