# Quit recursive function when a dynamic condition is met

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, if-statement, recursion

Using the function from [Generate all sequences of bits within Hamming distance t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40813022/generate-all-sequences-of-bits-within-hamming-distance-t):

```
void magic(char* str, int i, int changesLeft) {
        if (changesLeft == 0) {
                printf("%s\n", str);
                return;
        }
        if (i < 0) return;
        // flip current bit
        str[i] = str[i] == '0' ? '1' : '0';
        magic(str, i-1, changesLeft-1);
        // or don't flip it (flip it again to undo)
        str[i] = str[i] == '0' ? '1' : '0';
        magic(str, i-1, changesLeft);
}
```

I would like to quit the recursive function and return to the caller function when a certain condition occurs (if it does). So it's like my recursive function is hearing voices that might tell her to quit!

It only happens *after* `str` is printed, here:

```
if (changesLeft == 0) {
    printf("%s\n", str);
    int quit_now = voices(str);
    return;
}
```

How to do this (stop unfolding the recursion and return to the function caller)?

---

Attempt:

```
if (i < 0 || quit_now == 1) return;
```

just seems to block the execution and never end!

<sub>PS - I am interested even in [c](/questions/tagged/c) old methodologies.</sub>

Comment: Did you try goto: instead of return?

Comment: @hbagdi the black sheep? :O I have never touched it, but if you post an answer that proves it can come in handy, I would be willing to....I am over 21 now!!! =) // didn't get that was trolling :/

Comment: Don't.  They are trolling you.

Comment: Alternatively you could just consider a non-recursive implementation.

Comment: @AlexD if I had one, of course! Maybe I should try to write one (or if you have one already, feel free to post it as an answer)! :)

Comment: @gsamaras And another approach - but no, I'm not suggesting it as it is against best practices - to throw an exception :).

Comment: I would do that @AlexD, except if I had something else available! ;)

Comment: Agree that exceptions are a tool available.  But exceptions should be thrown in exceptional circumstances.  It's not clear whether this is one of those.

Comment: Pass a bool reference around and check it to terminate recursion.

Comment: @ddriver you mean something like paddy's solution? If not, post a new answer with that, if you like of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put it in the simplest form, you could do something like this:

```
void foo(bool & ret) {
  // doStuff...
  if (ret) return;
  foo(ret);
  // doStuff...
  if (ret) return;
  foo(ret);
}
```

Then you initiate the recursion:

```
bool ret = false;
foo(ret);
```

In your case you can interupt the recursion by

```
if (!changesLeft) {
  printf("%s\n", str);
  ret = true;
  return;
}
```

Setting to true will get you out of the entire call tree.

You can do it in C as well, just use a pointer rather than a reference.

Comment: This is actually similar to how I do "exception handling" in C - granted it is arduous, but if you want clean and proper stack unwinding that's the way to go. longjmp will whoosh past all the stuff that needs to happen along the stack frames, and you're gonna have a bad time. It is only acceptable if you don't have anything to handle - no deallcations, no de-initializations and so on.

Comment: Beware there can be memory ordering issues and race conditions accessing the true value of `ret` between threads, and a proper solution may involve the use of an atomic.

Comment: @paddy this really doesn't look like a multi-threaded scenario. And race condition protection in multi-threaded scenarios goes without saying.

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution, given your function currently has no return value, is to use it to indicate whether that terminating condition was met.  Then you can use it to immediately exit all recursive calls if the result becomes true.

Not sure if I'm capturing your expected logic correctly here, but the intuitive approach would be something like this:

```
int magic(char* str, int i, int changesLeft) {
    int result;
    if (changesLeft == 0) {
            printf("%s\n", str);
            return voices(str);
    }
    if (i < 0) return 0;

    // flip current bit
    str[i] = str[i] == '0' ? '1' : '0';
    result = magic(str, i-1, changesLeft-1);

    if( !result ) {
        // or don't flip it (flip it again to undo)
        str[i] = str[i] == '0' ? '1' : '0';
        result = magic(str, i-1, changesLeft);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: And `result` should get its value **right**  after `printf("%s\n", str);`, as I would like to, right?

Comment: Yes, in each caller, because you return 1 after that `printf`.  And every caller up the stack stops making recursive calls when they get a non-zero result.  They all return that result to pass it all the way back up.  Another bonus is that the first caller will know whether the operation met its terminating condition or not.  And so the function itself doesn't have to have the `printf`.  You could say: `if( magic(str, 0, x) ) printf( "OK: %s\n", str ); else printf( "No answer\n" );`

Comment: Oh, sorry, I only just noticed I hadn't handled the `voices` thing.  Copy/paste and lazy reading....  I've updated.

Answer (score 1):

The `magic` function calls itself recursively in two places.  So in each of those places, you need to check your exit condition.  The answer given by paddy details this.

An alternative for immediate unwinding of the stack is to use `setjmp` and `longjmp` which can function as a non-local `goto`.

```
jmp_buf magic_buf;

void magic_int(char* str, int i, int changesLeft) {
        if (changesLeft == 0) {
                printf("%s\n", str);
                if (voices(str)) {
                    longjmp(magic_buf, 1);
                }
                return;
        }
        if (i < 0) return;
        // flip current bit
        str[i] = str[i] == '0' ? '1' : '0';
        magic_int(str, i-1, changesLeft-1);
        // or don't flip it (flip it again to undo)
        str[i] = str[i] == '0' ? '1' : '0';
        magic_int(str, i-1, changesLeft);
}

void magic(char* str, int i, int changesLeft) {
    if (!setjmp(magic_buf)) {
        magic(str, i, changesLeft);
    }
}
```

The `setjmp` function returns `0` when called directly.  When `longjmp` is called, it is the `setjmp` function that actually returns, and the return value is the second parameter given to `longjmp`.

Here, we have a wrapper function which calls `setjmp`.  This sets the jump point for when `longjmp` is called.  Then the recursive function is called.  Later, when the recursive function "hears voices" telling it to quit **now**, it calls `longjmp` which immediately goes directly to the corresponding `setjmp` call.

These functions are specified in C99 as well as POSIX, so a POSIX conforming system (i.e. Linux) should still have these available in C89 mode.

If you were to do this in C++, the preferred method would be to throw an exception in the recursive function and catch it in the wrapper function.

```
struct magic_voices {
    int rval;
};

void magic_int(char* str, int i, int changesLeft) {
        if (changesLeft == 0) {
                printf("%s\n", str);
                int rval = voices(str);
                if (rval) {
                    struct magic_voices ex;
                    ex.rval = rval;
                    throw ex;
                }
                return;
        }
        if (i < 0) return;
        // flip current bit
        str[i] = str[i] == '0' ? '1' : '0';
        magic_int(str, i-1, changesLeft-1);
        // or don't flip it (flip it again to undo)
        str[i] = str[i] == '0' ? '1' : '0';
        magic_int(str, i-1, changesLeft);
}

void magic(char* str, int i, int changesLeft) {
    try {
        magic(str, i, changesLeft);
    } catch (struct magic_voices ex) {
        printf("rval=%d\n", ex.rval);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are these babies standard C/C++?

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages.  Use of explicit jumps in C++ is highly discouraged.  Especially for something as simple as ordinary termination of a recursion.  The compiler is free to decide on a jump if it wants to optimize the return.  The programmer should not be concerned with that detail under ordinary circumstances.

Comment: I think this is a useful answer, which provides insight into more of a systems-level approach.  It's good to know these things are there, but to exercise discretion about using them.

Comment: @paddy Added a C++ solution involving exceptions.

Comment: I think your solution will suffer from the same problem as paddy's, please see my update.

Comment: @gsamaras Two problems.  First your condition is backwards.  You should be setting `result = max >= MAX`.  Second, you want to `return result;` in the following line, not `return 1;`.  Also note that `max` is never being modified.

Comment: That did the trick `result = ++max >= MAX;  return result;`. Would you like to post another answer with that? I like your answer now, but it's more hardcore :P

Answer (score 1):

This is a non-recursive variant. Basically, it generates all increasing sequences `0 <= a[0] < ... < a[dist-1] < strlen(num)`, and reverts bits at corresponding indices.

```
void print(const char* num, const vector<int>& a) {
    size_t k = 0, n = strlen(num);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        if (k < a.size() && a[k] == i) {
            cout << (num[i] == '0') ? '1' : '0';
            ++k;
        }
        else
            cout << num[i];
    cout << endl;
}

void hamming(const char* num, size_t dist) {
    assert(dist > 0);
    vector<int> a(dist);
    size_t k = 0, n = strlen(num);
    a[k] = -1;
    while (true)
        if (++a[k] > n - dist + k)
            if (k == 0)
                return;
            else {
                --k;
                continue;
            }
        else
            if (k == dist - 1) {
                print(num, a);
                // conditional return here
            }
            else {
                a[k+1] = a[k];
                ++k;
            }
}
```

Which can be used like this:

```
int main()
{
    hamming("0000", 2);
    /* output:
       1100
       1010
       1001
       0110
       0101
       0011
    */
}
```

P.S. Thanks to **@ruakh** for mentioning a missing optimization in the `while - if` condition.

Comment: Alex, sorry for commenting after so much time, but wouldn't that `cout << (num[i] == '0') ? '1' : '0';` be more naturally written as `cout << (num[i] == '0') ? '0' : '1';`, or it should be the way you wrote it? Oh, it has to be the way you wrote it, but why? =)

Comment: @gsamaras The vector `a` is supposed to keep indices for which bits have to be inverted. So if `a` contains the current index `i`, we print `1` instead of `0` and vice versa. Otherwise we print the bit as is (see `else`-part).

Comment: Thank you AlexD, I am very intrigued by the algorithm and trying to analyze its Time Complexity, as [shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41086928/time-complexity-of-an-iterative-algorithm).

Comment: @gsamaras Oh, sorry, if I'd know it is intended for `O`-complexity, I would be more accurate and remove dry run, as ruakh suggested! I added a comment to Paul's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41088194/3246555).