# Mapping standard number n bits to new system of n bits based on the amount of enabled bits

Tags: mapping, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to figure out a way to map numbers from our standard way of counting bits (binary) to a system where primarily the the cardinality of the bits in a number and then secondary the position of enabled bits in a number are used to map this said number to a new number ordered by the rules described. I've struggled to come up with a general fast method for any amount of bits. I want to know what methods there are for doing this and what is the best time complexity that can be achieved.

I provided an example mapping with 4 bits to make my question more clear.

```
0   0000    0
1   0001    1
2   0010    2
4   0100    3
8   1000    4
3   0011    5
5   0101    6
9   1001    7
6   0110    8
10  1010    9
12  1100    10
7   0111    11
11  1011    12
13  1101    13
14  1110    14
15  1111    15
```

I really don't know how to classify this problem in order to do more research on it. If anybody knows how to label this specifically and would like to share that with me I would be most grateful.

Comment: why is `1001` before `0110` in the set of values with 2 set bits?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8281951/10396