# All subsets of size k, maximize difference between subsets

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

Stock algorithms for enumerating all subsets of size *k* (from a set of size *N*) (e.g. as described here: [generate all subsets of size k from a set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555565/generate-all-subsets-of-size-k-from-a-set)) tend to use a "lexicographic" order, in which the leftmost element varies slowest.  I've also found an algorithm that minimizes the difference between successive subsets in the enumeration, kinda like a [Gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code).

I would like instead at each step to generate a subset which is maximally different from *all preceding subsets*.  (This is **not** the same as "maximize difference between successive subsets" as in the previous formulation of the question.)  For instance, considering subsets of size 4 from a set of size 8, one acceptable order begins

```
ABCD
    EFGH
AB    GH
  CDEF
AB  EF
  CD  GH
```

Note that the base set is large enough that holding <sub>n</sub>C<sub>k</sub> items in memory is impractical.

Answer (score 1):

In your desired output the number of elements that differ from one subset to the next gives the sequence `2,1,2,1,2`.  I get the same sequence by selecting, from the lexicographically-ordered list of subsets, the first, then the last, then the second, then the second last, *etc*.  At each step choose the subset which is furthest away in the order and which has not already been chosen.

I don't get the same sequence of subsets, just the same sequence of numbers of differences.

I've satisfied myself that this works for a couple of other small cases too and am now looking forward to the counter-examples and down votes.

Ahh, so you don't want to rely on building the lexicographically-ordered set of subsets first.  My initial thought is to have 2 subset generators running at the same time, one starting at the first subset (*eg* `AB`) and going forward, the other starting at the last (*eg* `CD`) and going backwards.  If you get what I mean.

Comment: You have made me realize that I formulated the problem incorrectly.  Please see edit.  (The difference only becomes apparent with larger sets than I had in the example.  Your solution doesn't provide sufficiently large gaps between set *n* and set *n* + 2.)