# Find sum of gcd of all subsequence of size K from 1 to n (in O(nlogn))

Tags: arrays, time-complexity, subsequence

Suppose a[]={1,2,3,4,5} and K=3

Sum of gcd of all subsequence of size k = `gcd(1,2,3)+gcd(1,2,4)+gcd(1,2,5)+gcd(1,3,4)+gcd(1,3,5)+gcd(1,4,5)+gcd(2,3,4)+gcd(2,3,5)+gcd(2,4,5)+gcd(3,4,5).`

How can we find this for different values of k?

- 2<=k<=100000
- 1<=n<=100000

Comment: Start by coding a routine that generates all subsequence of `a` and the rest is one loop around it with a sum.

Comment: but the time complexity to find subsequence is (O(n^2))

Comment: Can you give the pseudo code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555565/generate-all-subsets-of-size-k-from-a-set and for the gcd part https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gcd-two-array-numbers/

Comment: As for complexity since the size of the subsequence is n!/(k! (n-k)!) I hardly see how you could achieve O(n log n) with generating all subsequence as in your example.